# How to convert T to object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, generics

I am getting error to convert T to Entity

```
public T Add(T entity)
{
    CAFMEntities db = new CAFMEntities();
    db.TabMasters.AddObject((TabMaster)entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

It is giving me an error:

> Cannot convert type 'T' to 'CAFM.Data.EntityModel.TabMaster'

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, how do you want the conversion to apply? Where is T declared? You may be able to change it so that you have:

```
class WhateverClass<T> where T : TabMaster
```

at which point you don't need the cast. Or if you *can't* constrain `T`, you can use:

```
db.TabMasters.AddObject((TabMaster)(object) entity);
```

An alternative is:

```
db.TabMasters.AddObject(entity as TabMaster);
```

although personally I'm not as fond of that - I prefer the stricter checking of the cast.

Comment: @abatishchev: Apparently so, although of course then you don't get as good checking. Will add that in as an option.

Comment: @abatischev Not with your post as is: `as` only works with reference types, but `T` is not constrained as such ... now if `where T : class` (or otherwise constrained to another reference type), then yes.

Comment: @pst: Nope, you don't need to constrain T in order to use `as`. I've just tried it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet `void x<T>() { return null as T; } void Main () { x<string>(); }` gets me "The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint" in LINQPad4.

Comment: Well, duh. `TabMaster` is simply a reference type. Underwhelming explanation.

Comment: @pst: That's trying to convert *to* `T` - the OP is trying to convert *from* `T`. I'm not sure where your last comment is aimed...